# Difference between Task.Delay() and new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep())

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-sleep

I was putting together a small little demo to take a long running method simulated with a `Thread.Sleep()` and wanted to add async to easily go from a synchronous process to an async one.  Here's the initial code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LongProcess();
}

private void LongProcess()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value += 3;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    progressBar1.Value += 1;
}
```

I was thinking I could simply change the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` into a `new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(1000))`, like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LongProcess();
}

private async void LongProcess()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value += 3;
        await new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(1000));
    }
    progressBar1.Value += 1;
}
```

However this never returns to the loop after the first await.  If I change the Thread.Sleep to a Task.Delay everything works, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work.  I assume something is getting blocked forever, but it doesn't quite make sense.  Can anyone explain how my code works, and a possible solution without changing to Task.Delay (just so I can get another perspective of how this works)?

Comment: `await new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(1000))` this is "indirect" way to do the same as `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. In addition, is not compatible with .Net 2.0/3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task.Delay` isn't same as staring a Task with `Thread.Sleep`. `Task.Delay` uses `Timer` internally and thus it doesn't blocks any thread, however starting a new Task with `Thread.Sleep` blocks the thread (typically Threadpool thread).

In your example you never started the `Task`. Creating a `Task` with constructor will return a `Unstarted` task needs to be started with a call to `Start` method. Otherwise it will never complete(because you never started it).

However calling `Task.Start` is discouraged, You can call `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> Thread.Sleep(1000))` or `Task.Run(()=> Thread.Sleep(1000))` if you want to **waste a resource**.

Also, be aware that [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), you should prefer `Task.Run` over `StartNew` unless there's a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: And it is especially problematic when the execution of the task gets delegated to UI thread.

Comment: @Euphoric I think now I addressed your comment in my answer with the link to stephen's blog.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am just doing this for academic purposes to understand the underlying pieces at work so I appreciate the extra info

Comment: `StartNew` isn't dangerous. You are putting words into Mr Cleary's mouth.

Comment: @Gusdor Not sure what you mean. Are you sure you read the blog post by stephen? *StartNew is Dangerous* is the blog title indeed. Readers shouldn't only read the title, but the content also.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel in the code example, the author explicitly tells the offending code to run on the UI. This is a contrived example.

Comment: @Gusdor Why it was contrived? Just to show that it could happen, so be careful. I don't think creating awareness is any wrong, and not sure what's your point still. I'm giving a reference to a article for bonus reading, and not just saying heyy don't use `StartNew` it is dangerous. (Edit:) just realized you edited your comment, yes prefer `Task.Run` over `StartNew` unless you need more options, but be aware of the problem though.

Comment: It seems we agree. I simply want to make sure that readers do not have their confidence in TPL broken because of such strong language.

Comment: @Gusdor Getting exception is not same something happening which is not what the author intended. You seem to miss that very important point. I really want readers to be careful, push them to the "Pit of success". Hope our comments here will also help them, thanks.

Comment: @Gusdor yes it uses `ThreadPool` thread but for `63` Timers only one thread will be used, it isn't significant to be noted IMO.

Answer (score 4):

`new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(1000))` creates a Task, but doesn't start it.

You can use `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))` or `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))` to create and start a task.

Comment: Yeah that make sense, I thought the start with implied if I was awaiting it.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question title - `Task.Delay` is cancellable!

Consider a popular implementation using `TaskCompletionSource`.

```
static Task Delay(int delayTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken token)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        if (delayTime < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Delay time cannot be under 0");

        System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(p =>
        {
            timer.Dispose(); //stop the timer
            tcs.TrySetResult(null); //timer expired, attempt to move task to the completed state.
        }, null, delayTime, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

        token.Register(() =>
            {
                timer.Dispose(); //stop the timer
                tcs.TrySetCanceled(); //attempt to mode task to canceled state
            });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

You cannot do this with `Thread.Sleep`. You *can* do it with a big old loop but that simply emulates the underlying `Timer` in the code above.