# Is it possible to set timeout for tasks in a List<Task> and cancell only the long runing tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

Im new with c# (and with english language too), i try do some work in background parallel. I have a list with "MyClass" objects. Each has a "DoWork()" function, i put this functions in a List then i'll run all. I have 2 questions: 1, Is it all wrong? 2, when the first answere is "no", then is it possible to set a max running time to functions (when a "DoWork()" take more than 600ms, then i want to stop it, but the others no.)? Sorry for my bad english!

Here is my code:

```
public class MyClass
{
        static int nextId;
        public int id;
        public int x;
        public MyClass()
        {
            id = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextId);
            x = (id % 4 + 1) * 250; 
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Console.Write("start: {0}", this.id);
            Thread.Sleep(x);  //this  simulate  the  work
            Console.WriteLine("end:  {0}", this.id);
        }
}
```

in main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < db; i++)
{
    xy_list.Add(new MyClass());
}

List<Task> tasks3 = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in xy_list)
{
   Task work = new Task(() => item.DoWork());                
   tasks3.Add(work);    
}
Parallel.ForEach(tasks3, task => 
{ 
      task.Start(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do some work here yourself. Cancellation of tasks is a cooperative process (see [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information).

To be able to cancel your background tasks and have them time-out, you will need to create a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh139229(v=vs.110).aspx) that you provide with a timeout. This token source can be used to provide cancellation tokens to the tasks that you are starting, and you also need to pass them on to the `DoWork` method, that should check if cancellation is requested.

If you constructed the cancelation token source with a timeout, it will signal all connected cancellation tokens to cancel when the timeout has expired.

Using this on your code example, would make it look something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static int nextId;
    public int id;
    public int x;
    public MyClass()
    {
        id = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextId);
        x = (id % 4 + 1) * 250; 
    }
    public void DoWork(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        bool is_canceled = false;
        while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested && cycle < 5)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} waiting, tid = {1}", id, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Task.Delay(x / 5, cancelToken).Wait(); // don't do Thread.Sleep()
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} waking up, tid = {1}", id, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerExceptions.Any(x => typeof(OperationCanceledException).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task {0} canceled, tid = {1}", id, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    is_canceled = true;
                    break;
                }
                throw;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} canceled, tid = {1}", id, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                is_canceled = true;
            }
            cycle++;
        }
        is_canceled |= cycle < 5;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, tid = {2}", this.id, is_canceled ? "canceled" : "completed", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

And in your "main":

```
for (int i = 0; i < db; i++)
{
    xy_list.Add(new MyClass());
}

// set cancellation timeout for 600 ms.
var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600));

// start all tasks
List<Task> tasks3 = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in xy_list)
    tasks3.Add(Task.Run(() => item.DoWork(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token));

// Wait for all tasks to be finished.
Task.WaitAll(tasks3.ToArray());
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but you're using Task.Delay the wrong way...it returns a Task that will complete in the given time but doesn't magically make the thread wait. What you could do (while staying in sync context) is call Task.Delay(x).Wait() - but that's pretty much the same as calling Thread.Sleep in the first place. Task.Delay is more intended to use with async/await

Comment: @Linky, your are partially right, thanks. I modified the sample. Your comment on `Task.Delay(...).Wait()` being pretty much the same as `Thread.Sleep()` is not correct. `Task.Delay()` will use a (cancelable) timer for waking up. Refer to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820626/difference-between-task-delay-and-new-task-thread-sleep

Comment: @Linky Please refer to my previous edit that already included the `Task.Delay(x / 5, cancelToken).Wait()` statement. I only added explicit logging in this latest edit.

Comment: Sorry - really sorry...i misread and overlooked the token you passed. My fault, sorry. You want me to delete the comments?

Comment: @Linky, You should decide that for yourself. Your first comment was partially right, pointed out an error in the code of my original answer and allowed me to improve it. So I would not remove that comment.