# Thread.Sleep and Task.Delay kill the main thread in a looped process

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I'm attempting to add a 10 second delay between each message in a looped asynchronous email sender. The reason for the delay is to limit the number of emails being sent within a given time period.

It works, but as soon as I add the 10 second delay to the loop using either Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay, the main thread just seems to drop so that only the first email is sent.

Here is my code:

```cs
    Task t = Task.Run( async ( ) =>
    {
        foreach( var message in messages )
        {
            using( var client = new SmtpClient( ) )
            {
                await client.SendMailAsync( message );
                message.Dispose( );
            }
            // all of these seem to kill the main thread
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ) );
            await Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ) );
            //await new Task( ( ) => Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ) ) );
        }
    } );
```

I looked at [Difference between Task.Delay() and new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820626/difference-between-task-delay-and-new-task-thread-sleep), but the it looks like I am using the solution, which doesn't work for me here. Any ideas?

Comment: my understanding is that  `await Task.Delay()` will not suspend the entire thread, but just the single task you want to suspend. All other tasks on the same thread can continue running.

Comment: You are not `await`ing the first `t` task thus making it a _fire-and-forget_ task.  If the next line is say the end of a console app's `Main()`, then the program is going to exit before the rest of the tasks complete. Removing the delay is going to increase the probability that the other tasks complete in time. Please post some more of your code. i.e. console app? WinForms? What is the next line?

Comment: Thanks guys. It's a ASP.NET web application. That's all the code I have. It passes in a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` from a `List<System.Net.Mail.MailMessage>`, creates the `SmtpClient` and sends the email asynchronously. Did you want me to add a runnable sample?

Comment: Why do you want a delay in an ASP.NET application? That makes no sense.

Comment: Hi @Henk, the delay in a ASP.NET Application is actually a delay in sending multiple emails over a specified period of time. Our mail service requires us to send a maximum of 30 messages per minute otherwise we could get flagged as spamming. Adding a delay to bulk reminders limits the number of emails that are sent per minute and keeps us under the spam radar. Not eloquent, but a simple solution. The alternative is to purchase a bulk email service, which we will eventually, but it's all extra $$$.

Comment: Otherwise, yes, you're right @Henk. ASP.NET Applications don't need any more encouragement in respect of delays :-)

Comment: You should look up "background work on ASP.NET". And it has become a lot easier with ASP.NET core 2.x.  So tell us which branch of ASP.NET you're on.

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting the first task thus making it a *fire-and-forget* task. If the next line is say the end of a console app's `Main()`, then the program is going to exit before the rest of the tasks complete! Removing the delay is going to increase the probability that the other tasks complete in time.

> It's a ASP.NET web application.

In that case you should be using `async` *"all the way"* which means that not only should you have an `await` here:

```
Task t = Task.Run( async ( ) => { ... }
```

...becoming

```
await Task.Run( async ( ) => { ... }
```

...but also your whole call tree all the way back out to your ASP.NET controller method

```
public async Task SomeMethodOnMyController ()
{
    await SomethingAsync();
}

async Task SomethingAsync()
{
   // do something thrilling here

   await _emailSystem.SendEmailsAsync();

   // do something thrilling here
}
```

...where `SendEmailsAsync` is essentially your code provided in the question.

If you don't do this, then there is the chance ASP.NET will be unaware that the method is performing async operations and could prematurely recycle your AppDomain before your email processing is complete.

### EDIT: For ASP.NET WebForms

The example would be something like

```
protected async void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await // rest of code here;
}
```

### Tell me more

- *[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)*

Comment: Hi @MickeyD. This just didn't work for me. The async processing of the emails works very well (without the imposed delay). This is Web Forms BTW, so the UI initiates the call and passes the list of emails to the method. From there, the new thread takes over and all is well... Unless I add a manufactured delay!

Comment: @Scho What didn't work.  Did you get an error?  You probably need to show your UI callback method

Comment: @MickeyD No problems and thanks, I will put together a runnable sample for you.

Comment: @MickeyD I suspect what I am attempting to achieve is not supported and indicates that the whole premise for delaying the email processing requires a proper solution instead of a 'hack' to limit the number of emails being sent within a given time frame. I attempted to create a runnable sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/UT1taZ but this simply builds in a delay and then the results suddenly appear in the UI. Bad code, little understanding of threading and ultimately a bad idea.

Comment: That said, I appreciate your effort and patience and I now have a better appreciation for threading and the existence of email services like SendGrid that are designed to cope with bulk emails.

Comment: @Scho Not a problem good sir.   Good luck with future coding, remember if you ever get stuck, feel free to post it as a new question. :)